# Typescript keyof exclude methods

Tags: typescript

I want to exclude methods by using the `keyof` feature and `never`, but it doesn't work:

```
class A {
  prop = 1;
  save() {}  
  hello() {}
}

type ExcludeFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : T[K] 
};


function test<T>(param: T): ExcludeFunctionPropertyNames<T> {
  return { } as any;
}

test(new A()).prop; // I still see here `save` and `hello`
```

My understanding is that `never` should remove them.

Comment: well the key `save` is here but it is of type never. I am trying to make it work the way you want

Comment: The key hello is also there. It's not working as expected.

Comment: yes it is there also but the type of `save` and `hello` is now never

Comment: Right, typescript should exclude them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution to do what you are trying :

```
class A {
  prop = 1;
  save() {}  
  hello() {}
}

type ExcludeFunctionPropertyNames<T> = Pick<T, {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K
}[keyof T]>;

function test<T>(param: T): ExcludeFunctionPropertyNames<T> {
  return { } as any;
}

test(new A()) // only prop available;
```

You have all explanations in this article : https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c